# Game Center Leaderboard: "Done" not calling the delegate when in Leaderboards Overview

Tags: ios, gamekit, game-center

I have two leaderboards in a universal app (iPhone/iPad).
I am creating GKLeaderboardViewController using the code bellow:

```
GKLeaderboardViewController* lvc = [[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init];  
lvc.category = [self isIpad] ? @"ipadmain" : @"iphonemain";
lvc.leaderboardDelegate = self;
```

So far everything works fine.
When I tap on "Done" button, the view closes.

However, if I navigate to leaderboards overview via the "Leaderboards" button in the toolbar of GKLeaderboardViewController, "Done" is not working in the overview screen (delegate is not being called). If I navigate back to a specific board again, "Done" works.

Answer (score 0):

There is not really enough code in your post to figure out what is going on. What you have posted will not effect the delegate call back functionality, other than the line where you set the actual delegate. Since you are setting the delegate correctly, you should be getting the callback.

When you say the "delegate" is not getting called, does the delegate still exist?
Does the Leaderboard view controller disappear from the screen?

Comment: Yes delegate is still in place. It is that I navigated in the Leaderboard from a specific Leaderboard to the Overview screen (where all Leaderboards are displayed). In this Screen Done button is not working. The leaderboard does not closes. The delegate method is not called. However, this problems solved from alone. Without changing anything everything works fine right now. I just thought maybe someone had similar experience with GKLeaderboardViewController.